# Delay before redirect after button click

Tags: asp.net

I have read other questions and also used this in the past with no issues. But for some reason it will not work now. I have tried AppendHeader also.

Does anyone know why the response.addheader is not working? The below code is inside a button click. All the code is executed but no redirect. I changed the website link to avoid hacking. It is correct in my code.

When people update a vendor, it will display "Updated Successfully" and then redirect back to the overview page after a few seconds.

```
if (Request.QueryString["ID"] != null)
        {
            Int32 EquipValueID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["EquipValueID"]);
            Int32 ID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]);

            //update Value
            this.Master.Conn.ExecuteSql(VendorSQL.UpdateValue(VendorName, Status, EquipValueID));
            //update Manu
            this.Master.Conn.ExecuteSql(VendorSQL.UpdateManu(VendorName, ContactName, ContactTitle, Address, City, State, Zip, Country, Email, Phone, Fax, Notes, ID, Status));

            Result.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("color", "green");
            Result.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("font-weight", "bold");
            Result.Text = "Updated successfully!";
            Response.AddHeader("REFRESH", "2;URL=http://MYWEBSITE.com/Admin/Logistics/Vendor/Overview/Default.aspx");

        }
```

Comment: Why do you require a delay? Perhaps knowing that would give people better information when trying to come up with an answer.

Comment: What browser are you testing this in? The refresh header is non-standard, so it's possible that it's not supported any more.

Comment: Where you are trying to redirect? is it same page?

Comment: No, I am redirecting from an edit page back to the overview page. Testing in chrome, worked a week ago.

Comment: What if you simply say `Response.AddHeader("REFRESH", "2;URL=Default.aspx");`?

Comment: Wont work, in a different folder.

Comment: What I meant is .. try with relative address like `~/Admin/Logistics/Vendor/Overview/Default.aspx`

Comment: Thanks, but did not work. DO you know how to check if it is firing in debug?

Comment: NO, best suggestion is to test the same in some other browser and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easier way to do this. I put a asp:hiddenfield on the page and if I want to redirect after delay I set that to 1 using c#, and on the client if that hidden field is 1, then we do something like setTimeout(function(){location.href = 'test.aspx';}, 5000);

Hope this helps people.